# How can I setup tailwind css vscode extension with Dioxus?

Tags: rust, dioxus

I'm currently using Dioxus (Rust) for frontend WASM.

I'm looking to set up [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) (Tailwind is working through the CLI), but I can't seem to get it working.

```
// settings.json
 "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": ["class:s*\"([^\"]*)"],
  "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "rust": "html"
  }
```

Here's an example component:

```rust
use dioxus::{core::UiEvent, events::MouseData, prelude::*};
use std::cmp::{max, min};

#[derive(PartialEq, Props)]
pub struct NavbarProps<'a> {
    page_state: &'a UseState<i32>,
}

pub fn Navbar<'a>(cx: Scope<'a, NavbarProps<'a>>) -> Element<'a> {
    let go_next = move |_: UiEvent<MouseData>| cx.props.page_state.modify(|val| min(val + 1, 17));
    let go_prev = move |_: UiEvent<MouseData>| cx.props.page_state.modify(|val| max(val - 1, 1));

    cx.render(rsx! (
        div {
            button {
                class: "p-1 bg-red-300 ",
                onclick: go_prev,
                "<",
            }
            button {
                class: "p-1 bg-red-700",
                onclick: go_next,
                ">"
            }
        }
    ))
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the Tailwind CSS extension supports linting CSS classes inline Rust code? The documentation only lists `html`, `css`, or `javascript` as supported file interpretations.

Comment: Hi @E_net4thecommentflagger, I'm not so sure. I know you can make it interpret different languages within the extension's configuration.

Comment: That does not automatically make it support finding Tailwind classes in any code file. For one, HTML is very different from Rust.

Comment: Yew supports HTML syntax, and you can use the extension successfully. I was wondering if any configuration could support the `class` field in Dioxus as Yew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration worked for me with Dioxus:

```
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
   "class: \"(.*)\""
],
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "rust": "html"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

the extension and formatter are not very accurate. for every kind of code format need to add special regex.
for example this code format shape

```
class:"flex"
```

(only different is, the `"` after `:` has not any space)

need the regex like this for snippet work:

```
"class:\"(.*)\""
```

the different with above answer code is delete space between `:` and `/`